# refreshing height of html, body after appending content

Tags: jquery, html, css

i am appending content to the page on document load, after this I am using a light-box type overlay, the problem is that although the overlay is set to 100% height it only displays as high as the visible content, when you scroll down the overlay is not as high as the window.

I firebug shows that the html, body tags are not the full height of the window, they are not adjusting their height when I append the ajax content.

Is there a way to refresh these heights after i Have loaded the content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got a feeling I got around this once, but it was a bit of a hack.

Basically you load the ajax content into a new, hidden element (which is allowed to expand as tall as it needs to), then use jQuery to ask it's height.  Then apply that value to your shown element.

I think at the time I was trying to load blog posts into a div which expanded height-wise.

Edit:  This of course assumes you're willing to set absolute heights rather than use percentages.

Comment: I know what you mean but the problem with this solution is that i actually need the updated body height as i want the overlay to be the full height of the window, so using this method i would have to get the height of my header + content + footer to get appropriate height.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried these;
$(window).resize();
Or
$(document).resize();

Try calling one of those after your function.